# How to convert usual web project to Maven project properly? Got error java.lang.classNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, apache, maven, pom.xml

What i trying to do here is converting my spring mvc web project to maven project, but i got this error when i run my project

> SEVERE: Servlet [Jasper] in web application [/SpringJasperMaven] threw
>   load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1146)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

i already check my POM.xml, i think all .jar i need is in their place. here is my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SpringJasperMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring.Jasper.Maven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ant</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-tribes</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.68</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
      <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-i18n-es</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-i18n-fr</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-i18n-ja</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-websocket</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
      <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
      <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
      <version>2.1_3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
      <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta-regexp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta-regexp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasper-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jfree</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jfree</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-sandbox</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is my project structure :
[image]

and here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jasper</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/Jasper-Context.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jasper</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

and here is my Jasper-Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

      <context:component-scan base-package="net.javaonline.spring.jasper.controller"/>
      <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

      <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/Pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>



</beans>
```

what do i miss here?

Comment: What does it say in the `Problems` window?

Comment: @Abdullah Ahci where is the Problems window?

Comment: Click Window->Show View->Other, Search for problems and click it, and it will open a window looks like [this](https://docs.joomla.org/images/f/f2/Screenshot_eclipse_problem_20090603-1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Spring-webMVC dependency is required in the pom.xml which looks like you have already declared . Do one thing, perform a maven clean followed by a build again . Then check in lib whether it has DispatcherServlet now . I think this should work . May be maven wasn't able to build that properly.

Comment: you mean DispatcherServlet.jar? i cannot find it, i alread close the project and open it again, yet it still error